# LPCSTR, LPCTSTR and LPTSTR

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

What the difference between `LPCSTR`, `LPCTSTR` and `LPTSTR`?

Why do we need to do this to convert a string into a `LV` / `_ITEM` structure variable `pszText`:

```
LV_DISPINFO dispinfo;  
dispinfo.item.pszText = LPTSTR((LPCTSTR)string);
```

Comment: Could you say exactly what type "string" is? (e.g. CString)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question:

`LPCSTR` is a pointer to a const string (LP means [Long Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315311/what-is-a-long-pointer))

`LPCTSTR` is a pointer to a `const TCHAR` string, (`TCHAR` being either a wide char or char depending on whether UNICODE is defined in your project)

`LPTSTR` is a pointer to a (non-const) `TCHAR` string

In practice when talking about these in the past, we've left out the "pointer to a" phrase for simplicity, but as mentioned by lightness-races-in-orbit they are all pointers.

This is a great [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/cppstringguide1.aspx) describing C++ strings (see 2/3 the way down for a chart comparing the different types)

Comment: I quickly scanned that article - seems great, adding it to my bookmarks and will read it as soon as I have time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are technically correct - although in my experience it is common practice to leave out the "pointer to a...." description for brevity when referring to string types in C++

Comment: @JohnSibly: In C, yes. In C++, it absolutely shouldn't be!!

Comment: Notice that that codeproject article was written 15 years ago and, unless it gets updated, contains misleading assumptions about Unicode characters always being 2 bytes. That's entirely wrong. Even UTF16 is variable length... it is much better to say that wide characters are UCS-2 encoded, and that "Unicode" in this context refers to UCS-2.

Comment: It's a mess, Unicode characters were originally meant to be two bytes, but that turned out not to be enough. So UTF-16 was designed to shoehorn modern unicode into systems that were originally designed for 16 bit unicode. On modern windows a "wide string" is actually a sequence of UTF-16 code units.

Comment: Of course the characters outside the basic multilingual plane are pretty rare, so most of the time you can get away with ignoring this detail.

Comment: Hmm... in this case, @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I would add an addendum that it's okay to leave out the "pointer to a..." when referring to C-strings in C++, if-and-only-if referring specifically to (decayed) string literals, or when interfacing/working with code that's either written in C, relies on C types instead of C++ types, and/or has C linkage via `extern "C"`.  Apart from that, yeah, it definitely should need either the "pointer" bit, or specific description as a C string.

Answer (score 98):

Quick and dirty:

`LP` == **L**ong **P**ointer.  Just think pointer or char*

`C` = **C**onst, in this case, I think they mean the character string is a const, not the pointer being const.

`STR` is **string**

the `T` is for a wide character or char (TCHAR) depending on compiler options.

### Bonus Reading

From [What does the letter "T" in LPTSTR stand for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061017-03/?p=29363): <sup>[archive](https://archive.ph/3lqLY)</sup>

> ## What does the letter "T" in LPTSTR stand for?
>
> October 17th, 2006
>
> The “T” in LPTSTR comes from the “T” in TCHAR. I don’t know for certain, but it seems pretty likely that it stands for “text”. By comparison, the “W” in WCHAR probably comes from the C language standard, where it stands for “wide”.

Comment: T is not for wide character, it is for varying character type. W is for wide (as in WCHAR). If UNICODE is defined, TCHAR == WCHAR, otherwise TCHAR == CHAR.
So if UNICODE is not defined, LPCTSTR == LPCSTR.

Comment: that is why I wrote "depending on compile options"

Comment: I really love this type of explaining :) . Thanks so much

Comment: @jalf, So what does T stand for?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not sure. "Template" or "Type", possibly?

Comment: definitely not template and not type.  
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc

Comment: [**T** means **T**ext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061017-03/?p=29363)

Comment: @IanBoyd that link seems to have died? Do you know what the title of the article was?

Answer (score 64):

### 8-bit AnsiStrings

- `char`: 8-bit character *(underlying C/C++ data type)*
- `CHAR`: alias of `char` *(Windows data type)*
- `LPSTR`: null-terminated string of `CHAR` *(**L**ong **P**ointer)*
- `LPCSTR`: constant null-terminated string of `CHAR` *(**L**ong **P**ointer **C**onstant)*

### 16-bit UnicodeStrings

- `wchar_t`: 16-bit character *(underlying C/C++ data type)*
- `WCHAR`: alias of `wchar_t` *(Windows data type)*
- `LPWSTR`: null-terminated string of `WCHAR` *(**L**ong **P**ointer)*
- `LPCWSTR`: constant null-terminated string of `WCHAR` *(**L**ong **P**ointer **C**onstant)*

### depending on `UNICODE` define

- `TCHAR`: alias of `WCHAR` if UNICODE is defined; otherwise `CHAR`
- `LPTSTR`: null-terminated string of `TCHAR` *(**L**ong **P**ointer)*
- `LPCTSTR`: constant null-terminated string of `TCHAR` *(**L**ong **P**ointer **C**onstant)*

So:

| Item | 8-bit *(Ansi)* | 16-bit *(Wide)* | Varies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| character | `CHAR` | `WCHAR` | `TCHAR` |
| string | `LPSTR` | `LPWSTR` | `LPTSTR` |
| string (const) | `LPCSTR` | `LPCWSTR` | `LPCTSTR` |

### Bonus Reading

`TCHAR` → [*Text Char*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061017-03/?p=29363) *([archive.is](https://archive.fo/bWuoe))*

---

[**Why is the default 8-bit codepage called "ANSI"?**](https://archive.today/oV0B)

From [Unicode and Windows XP](https://web.archive.org/web/20060223061715/http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/8/56803da0-e4a0-4796-a62c-ca920b73bb17/21-Unicode_WinXP.pdf)
by Cathy Wissink
Program Manager, Windows Globalization
Microsoft Corporation
May 2002

> Despite the underlying Unicode support on Windows NT 3.1, code page support
> continued to be necessary for many of the higher-level applications and components included in the system, explaining the pervasive use of the “A” [ANSI] versions of the Win32 APIs rather than the “W” [“wide” or Unicode] versions. (The term “ANSI” as used to signify Windows code pages is a historical reference, but is nowadays a misnomer that continues to persist in the Windows community. The source of this comes from the fact that the Windows code page 1252 was originally based on an ANSI draft, which became ISO Standard 8859-1. However, in adding code points to the range reserved for control codes in the ISO standard, the Windows code page 1252 and subsequent Windows code pages originally based on the ISO 8859-x series deviated from ISO. To this day, it is not uncommon to have the development community, both within and outside of Microsoft, confuse the 8859-1 code page with Windows 1252, as well as see “ANSI” or “A” used to signify Windows code page support.)

Comment: Shame this answer will never make it to the top because it's so new.. that's really something SO needs to fix. This is the best answer by far.

Comment: This really helps me a lot while I am doing Unicode project at the work. Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer. I think it's worth adding that the unicode version uses UTF16, so each 16-bit chunk is not a character but a code-unit. The names are historical (when Unicode === UCS2).

Answer (score 8):

Adding to John and Tim's answer.

Unless you are coding for Win98, there are only two of the 6+ string types you should be using in your application

- `LPWSTR`
- `LPCWSTR`

The rest are meant to support ANSI platforms or dual compilations.  Those are not as relevant today as they used to be.

Comment: @BlueRaja, I was mainly referring to C based strings in my answer.  But for C++ I would avoid `std::string` because it is still an ASCII based string and prefer `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: You should be using LPTSTR and LPCTSTR unless you are calling the ASCII (*A) or widechar (*W) versions of functions directly. They are aliases of whatever character width you specify when you compile.

Comment: ...And now that Microsoft is working on making the `*A` versions of WinAPI compatible with the UTF-8 code page, they're suddenly a lot more relevant. ;P

Comment: In retrospect, it is now evident wchar_t was a mistake. MS should have gone with UTF-8. That's what most of the World is doing. Qt solves this beautifully with QString.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the second part of your question, you need to do things like

```
LV_DISPINFO dispinfo;  
dispinfo.item.pszText = LPTSTR((LPCTSTR)string);
```

because MS's `LVITEM` struct has an `LPTSTR`, i.e. a *mutable* T-string pointer, not an `LPCTSTR`. What you are doing is

1) convert `string` (a `CString` at a guess) into an `LPCTSTR` (which in practise means getting the address of its character buffer as a read-only pointer)

2) convert that read-only pointer into a writeable pointer by casting away its `const`-ness.

It depends what `dispinfo` is used for whether or not there is a chance that your `ListView` call will end up trying to **write** through that `pszText`. If it does, this is a potentially very bad thing: after all you were given a read-only pointer and then decided to treat it as writeable: maybe there is a reason it was read-only!

If it is a `CString` you are working with you have the option to use `string.GetBuffer()` -- that deliberately gives you a writeable `LPTSTR`. You then have to remember to call `ReleaseBuffer()` if the string does get changed. Or you can allocate a local temporary buffer and copy the string into there.

99% of the time this will be unnecessary and treating the `LPCTSTR` as an `LPTSTR` will work... but one day, when you least expect it...

Comment: You should avoid C style cast and use `xxx_cast<>()` instead.

Comment: @harper You are quite right -- but I was quoting the OP, that is the code he was asking about. If I'd written the code myself it would certainly have used `xxx_cast<>` rather than mixing two different bracket-based casting styles!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to 2nd part of the question is simply that `CString` class doesn't provide a direct typecast conversion by design and what you are doing is kind of cheat.

A longer answer is the following:

The reason you can typcast `CString` to `LPCTSTR` is because CString provides this facility by overriding `operator=`. By design it provides conversion to only `LPCTSTR` pointer so the string value can't be modified with this pointer.

In other words, it simply doesn't provide an overload `operator=` to convert the `CString` into `LPSTR` for the same reason as above. They don't want to allow altering the string value this way.

So essentially, the trick is to use the operator CString provide and get this:

```
LPTSTR lptstr = (LPCTSTR) string; // CString provide this operator overload
```

Now LPTSTR can be further type casted to LPSTR :)

```
dispinfo.item.pszText = LPTSTR( lpfzfd); // accomplish the cheat :P
```

The correct way to get `LPTSTR` from 'CString' is this though (complete example):

```
CString str = _T("Hello");
LPTSTR lpstr = str.GetBuffer(str.GetAllocLength());
str.ReleaseBuffer(); // you must call this function if you change the string above with the pointer
```

Again because the [GetBuffer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=msvc-160#getbuffer) returns `LPTSTR` for that reason that now  you can modify :)