# Standard C Convert ANSI to UNICODE

Tags: c, winapi

I'm learning C programming, and in the process trying to create a Windows GUI app.

I've noticed at MSDN documentation to new applications should use `UNICODE` encoding. With that in mind, I added the `-DUNICODE` flag to the compiler.

When calling the function `CreateWindowEx()` to create the window, the title gets all weird when I use a `char*`, and the compiler gives me an error saying the function is expecting `unsigned short*`.

How can I convert ANSI string to unsigned short?

Comment: You could just call `CreateWindowExA`, which is the ASCII version of that function, and let Windows itself handle any conversions that need to happen.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "ANSI string". Did you mean "ASCII string"?

Comment: @Barmar no they didn't. ASCII is a character set. Windows has the concept of the [ANSI code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) the reason they recommend using `wchar_t` instead of `char` is that the old "A" or "ansi" functions convert the strings internally and may have odd behavior

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26567820/332733) information about the different types

Comment: @DavidGrayson There is no *"ASCII"* version of the Win32 API. You must be thinking of a different library.

Comment: @Barmar, Re "*There's no such thing as an "ANSI string".*", Yes there is. It means a string encoded according to the process's ANSI Code Page aka Active Code Page. This is typically 1252 on US machines.

Comment: @ikegami As Mgetz already corrected me. I didn't know that Windows-specific concept.

Comment: Huh @IInspectable ? I'm not trying to make some complicated statement, just saying "CreateWindowExA" is a version of the "CreateWindowEx" function that takes ASCII input, or "ASCII version" for short.

Comment: @DavidGrayson that is incorrect. The `A` functions take **ANSI** strings, not **ASCII** strings. Two very different things. ASCII is a *subset* of ANSI (or more accurately, most ANSI encodings including ASCII characters), but ANSI encodings have other characters that are not found in ASCII at all. Different machines can be configured to run with different ANSI codepages as their native encodings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateWindowEx()` is a preprocessor macro. When `UNICODE` is defined, it is an alias for [`CreateWindowExW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw), which takes `wchar_t*`<sup>1</sup> strings.  When `UNICODE` is not defined, it is an alias for [`CreateWindowExA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa) instead, which takes `char*` strings.

```
// in winuser.h...
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateWindowEx  CreateWindowExW
#else
#define CreateWindowEx  CreateWindowExA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

<sup>1</sup> In Visual Studio, `wchar_t` is an alias for `unsigned short` in C, or if the [`/Zc:wchar_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-wchar-t-wchar-t-is-native-type?view=msvc-170) compiler option is turned off in C++.

So, you can either:

- turn off `UNICODE` and call `CreateWindowEx()`, or call `CreateWindowExA()` directly, either way passing in your `char*` strings.
- if you are passing string literals into `CreateWindowExW()` (whether called directly, or when calling `CreateWindowEx()` with `UNICODE` enabled), prepend the literals with the special `L` prefix to make them `wchar_t*` strings, eg: `L"..."`. When passing string literals into the `CreateWindowEx()` macro, you should wrap them in the [`TEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) macro instead, eg: `TEXT("...")`, which will prepend them with the `L` prefix when `UNICODE` is defined.
- use the [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) (or equivalent) function at runtime.

Comment: What on earth would be the point of deciding to code for Unicode and then calling CreateWindowExA? I never understand why people would suggest that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan just because the Win32 API gets used in Unicode mode doesn't guarantee the rest of the user's code is Unicode-enabled. Sometimes `char` strings have to be mixed with `wchar_t` APIs, and vice versa, hence the suggestion that users should call the `A` or `W` API that matches the encoding of the data being used for each call. Obviously, when a user starts a new project, they should pick an encoding and be consistent with it. But when dealing with legacy code, that is not always possible.

Comment: did you read the question title? I don't understand your stance here at all. Unless of course the idea is to use UTF8.