# Why do fancy pointers exist?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, iterator

I've always seen pointers as a specialization of iterators, used in the particular case where objects are stored contiguously in memory. However, I found out that the Allocator member type `pointer` (which then defines the same member type on iterators and containers) is not required to be a real pointer but it may be what's called a fancy pointer that, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator),

> is used to access objects allocated in address spaces that differ from the homogeneous virtual address space.

This is what I used to call an iterator but not a pointer, but that's not the point. I'm wondering how an Allocator is not required to allocate contiguous memory. Imagine passing a custom allocator to `std::vector` that does not allocate objects in a contiguous manner. For me that's not a vector anymore. If I don't want objects to be contiguous in memory I use a list rather than a vector with a custom allocator. They just look like a big source of confusion, why were they introduced?

Comment: *Imagine passing a custom allocator to std::vector that does not allocate objects in a contiguous manner.* The vector is going to request a pointer to s specifically sized chunk of memory.  If you allocator lies and returns a pointer to memory of insufficient space then you have UB.  Garbe in - Garbage out

Comment: @NathanOliver what I'm saying is that the allocator may not return a contiguous chuck of memory. `std::vector` accesses the allocated memory using `Allocator::pointer` that may act as a LegacyRandomAccessIterator, but not as a LegacyContiguousIterator, thus making the vector work as a list

Comment: *what I'm saying is that the allocator may not return a contiguous chuck of memory.*.  It can't, or at least it is non-compliant if it does.  On the page you linked to look at the requirements for `allocate`.  It returns an array of size `n`.  Arrays are contiguous, no way around that.  The reason you can have a fancy pointer, is because you can be a in a structure like a list where each node is allocated with a separate call to `allocate`.  That wont happen in a vector though as it only grabs a single appropriately sized chunk of memory to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've always seen pointers as a specialization of iterators

Iteration of arrays is one of the uses of pointers. It is not their only purpose. They are also used as a "handle" to identify dynamic allocations.

> why were [fancy pointers] introduced?

The page that you linked explains a reason for their introduction:

> Such pointers were introduced to support segmented memory architectures ...

These days, such architectures are quite rare, but programmers have found other use cases:

> ... and are used today to access objects allocated in address spaces that differ from the homogeneous virtual address space that is accessed by raw pointers. An example of a fancy pointer is the mapping address-independent pointer [boost::interprocess::offset_ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html), which makes it possible to allocate node-based data structures such as std::set in shared memory and memory mapped files mapped in different addresses in every process.

The standard paper [P0773R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0773r0.html#A) linked in the linked page has a more detailed list of purposes:

> - Scenario A. "Offset" pointers with a modified bit-level representation.
> - Scenario B. Small-data-area "near" pointers.
> - Scenario C. High-memory-area "far" pointers.
> - Scenario D. "Fat" pointers carrying metadata for dereference-time.
> - Scenario E. "Segmented" pointers carrying metadata for deallocate-time.

Note that not all standard library implementations support all use cases of fancy pointers for all standard containers as explored in P0773R0.

Answer (score 3):

So, C++ as a language has a concept of a pointer. For any type `T*`, the language requires certain specific things out of it. In particular, `sizeof(T*)` is statically-determined, and all language pointers have the same size.

In the long-before time however, the things that `T*` could work with did not reflect hardware capabilities. Imagine if hardware had two pools of memory, but these pools of memory have different maximum sizes. So if the compiler mapped `T*` to the smaller pool, then one could not have a `T*` that points to the larger pool of memory. After all, the address space of the larger memory would exceed the size of `T*`.

This led to the use of [things like `LONG_POINTER`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315311/what-is-a-long-pointer) and the like for "pointing" into memory outside of the `T*` accessible space.

The goal of the `allocator::pointer` concept is to be able to write an allocator that can allow any allocator-aware container to work with such non-`T*`-compatible pools of memory *transparently*.

Of course... that is no longer relevant for most hardware. Virtual memory, 32 and 64-bit addressing, and the like are now standard. As such, if there's memory that's not directly accessible and you want to address it, the expectation is that you'll *convert* such memory into virtual addresses via OS calls which can then be used with language pointers just fine. See mapping of files and GPU memory.

It was intended to solve a problem at the library level, but the problem was instead solved at the hardware/OS level. Thus, it's an unnecessary complication of allocators and allocator-aware containers, but it remains present because of decisions made nearly 25 years ago.

Comment: Sidenote: Standard has moved to using `std::allocator_traits<A>::pointer` instead of `allocator::pointer`.

Comment: @eerorika, it is better `A::pointer` for consistency.