# Confused about all the different string types and how to use them properly in Visual C++

Tags: string, visual-c++

Years ago, I used to do some basic programming in C.  Now I am attempting to relearn what I have forgotten as well as learn Visual C++.  I am confused though by all the string options and now the extra layer of trying to make my programs Unicode compatible.  I have been reading Beginning Visual C++ 2010 as well as online reading to learn this information.

As an exercise I am writing a very basic program that asks a user to input some text and then display that text in the form of a messagebox. The program works, but my way of getting it to work was more through guesswork and looking at other examples than truly understanding why I need to convert the various strings into different types.

The code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Windows.h"

using std::wcin;
using std::wcout;
using std::wstring;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wstring myInput;

    wcout << "Enter a string: ";

    getline(wcin, myInput);

    MessageBoxW(NULL, myInput.c_str(), _T("Test MessageBox"), 64);

    return 0;
}
```

The MessageBox syntax is:

```
int WINAPI MessageBox(
  __in_opt  HWND hWnd,
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpText,
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpCaption,
  __in      UINT uType
);
```

On the other hand, if I just use the command line argument as the text of the messagebox, I do not need to convert the string at all and I am not sure why.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Windows.h"

using std::wcout;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    MessageBoxW(NULL, argv[1], _T("Test MessageBox"), 64);

    return 0;
}
```

My confusion is:

1. Why do I need to use the c_str() for argument 2 to MessageBoxW and why do I need to use the _T() macro (?) in argument 3?
2. Why did the program work in the second code example without doing some sort of conversion?
3. What exactly does LPCTSTR mean? I see another variant in MSDN functions called LPTSTR.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/lpcstr-lpctstr-and-lptstr)

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** .c_str() is a **standard** C++ method to convert from C++ strings to C strings. **_tmain, _T('x'), _T("text") and _TCHAR** are (somewhat ugly) **Microsoft** macros that make your program compile either in unicode or non-unicode mode. There's a global setting in the project options that set some macros to configure your project in one of these two modes.

If you are in non-unicode mode (referred to as ANSI mode in MS's documentation) the macros expand to:

**main, 'x', "text", char**

If you are in unicode mode, the macros expand to

**wmain, L'x', L"text", wchar_t**

**2)** and **3)** Windows headers are full of typedefs and macros like that. Sometimes they make code more obscure thant it needs to be. In general, **LP** means pointer (long pointer, i guess, but it's been a while since we needed to distinguish between near and far pointers), **C** means "const", **T** means that it will be either char or wchar_t depending on project settings and **STR** is obviously "string". After all, it's a plain C type, that's why you can pass C strings to them without conversion.

Answer (score 0):

1. The MessageBoxW function is expecting a C-style wide-character string (WCHAR *).  The macro _L() alters your string so that it's Unicode compatible (WCHAR* instead of char*).
2. argv[] doesn't do objects, so you're already getting a WCHAR pointer out of it.
3. LPCTSTR is basically a WINAPI typedef for const char * or const WCHAR*, depending on whether you are building as UNICODE.  Also see this post: [LPCSTR, LPCTSTR and LPTSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/lpcstr-lpctstr-and-lptstr)

In short, your main function is being passed WCHAR* strings and MessageBoxW expects WCHAR* strings.

Comment: But by creating a variable of wstring, is that already a wide string?  Why would I then need to use the c_str() function?