# convert an unsigned char to LPCSTR

Tags: c++

Hi i'm using VS2010 and MBCS. Can anyone tell me how to convert an unsigned char to LPCSTR? Sorry i'm only new to c++...:) Thanks

This is the code it is failing on:

```
    hr = MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "LOCKCODE",  szLockCode);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to set LOCKCODE");
```

`szLockCode` is the variable that needs to be converted.

Comment: Could you please provide 1) error massage and 2) szLockCode declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unsigned char array (`unsigned char szLockCode[10]` for instance) is technically already an LPCSTR. If you're using an array already then conversion is not the issue, if not, then you need an array. If you want a single character string, then you need an array of length 2. The character goes in the first position (`szLockCode[0]`) and the value 0 goes in the second position (`szLockCode[1]`).

Answer (score -1):

You probably get error message like:

> cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

To avoid it you should either do type convertion:

```
hr = MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "LOCKCODE",  (LPCSTR)szLockCode);
```

or use L prefix before string:

```
LPCSTR szLockCode = L"Some error";
hr = MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "LOCKCODE",  szLockCode );
```

Here is a good explanation of what LPCSTR stand for:

[LPCSTR, LPCTSTR and LPTSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/lpcstr-lpctstr-and-lptstr)

Comment: -1: Absolutely don't just cast to LPCSTR if the error indicates that wrong wide/ansi type is being passed!