# How to convert unsigned char to LPCTSTR in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, pointers, casting, arrays

```
BYTE name[1000];
```

In my `visual c++` project there is a variable defined `name` with the `BYTE` data type. If i am not wrong then `BYTE` is equivalent to `unsigned char`. Now i want to convert this `unsigned char *` to `LPCTSTR`.

How should i do that?

Comment: You really should not as BYTE is not necessary TCHAR - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/lpcstr-lpctstr-and-lptstr

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually it is a project and i have to update it. So i can't use it TCHAR :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LPCTSTR` is defined as either `char const*` or `wchar_t const*` based on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not.

- If `UNICODE` is defined, then you need to convert the *multi-byte string* to a *wide-char string* using `MultiByteToWideChar`.
- If `UNICODE` is *not* defined, a simple cast will suffice: `static_cast< char const* >( name )`.

This assumes that `name` is a *null-terminated c-string*, in which case defining it `BYTE` would make no sense. You should use `CHAR` or `TCHAR`, based on how are you operating on `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign 'name' variable to CString object directly like:

```
CString strName = name;
```

And then you can call CString's GetBuffer() or even preferably GetString() method which is more better to get LPCTSTR. The advantage is CString class will perform any conversions required automatically for you. No need to worry about Unicode settings.

```
LPCTSTR pszName = strName.GetString();
```