# How to convert string to LPSTR in WinAPI function which stores output in string

Tags: string, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to store some contents into a string variable by passing it as a parameter in various types of Windows API functions which accepts variable like char *.

For example, my code is:-

```
std::string myString;
GetCurrentDirectoryA( MAX_PATH, myString );
```

Now how do I convert the string variable to LPSTR in this case.

Please see, this function is not meant for passing the contents of string as input, but the function stores some contents into string variable after execution. So, myString.c_str( ) is ruled out.

Edit: I have a workaround solution of removing the concept of string and replacing it with something like

```
char myString[ MAX_PATH ];
```

but that is not my objective. I want to make use of string. Is there any way possible?

Also casting like

```
GetCurrentDirectoryA( MAX_PATH, ( LPSTR ) myString );
```

is not working.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, people rewrite the Windows functions they need to be `std::string` friendly, like this:

```
std::string GetCurrentDirectoryA()
{
  char buffer[MAX_PATH];
  GetCurrentDirectoryA( MAX_PATH, buffer );
  return std::string(buffer);
}
```

or this for wide char support:

```
std::wstring GetCurrentDirectoryW()
{
  wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
  GetCurrentDirectoryW( MAX_PATH, buffer );
  return std::wstring(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`LPTSTR` is defined as `TCHAR*`, so actually it is just an ordinary C-string, *BUT* it depends on whether you are working with ASCII or with Unicode in your code. So do

```
LPTSTR lpStr = new TCHAR[256];
ZeroMemory(lpStr, 256);
//fill the string using i.e. _tcscpy
const char* cpy = myString.c_str();
_tcscpy (lpStr, cpy);
//use lpStr
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kk6xf663(v=vs.80).aspx) for a reference on `_tcscpy` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/lpcstr-lpctstr-and-lptstr) thread.

Comment: Hi, did you mean .c_str( ) or is there something like .c_star( ). I am not able to search it. Also, I am using ASCII. So, according to my edited question, is the workaround solution given by me better or do you recommend me to use your proposed solution. Please can you contrast both the methods to me.

Comment: It was the autocorrect of my tablet! I do mean  `c_str()` of course! I use the generic approach which is common. In order to preserve genericity my approach is better. If you are fine with your approach then use it, as it provides a simpler, but non-generic way.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I would read the data into a TCHAR and then copy it into my std::string. That's the simplest way.