# CString To Byte and Byte To CByteArray Conversion-MFC

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, mfc, byte, c-strings

I have tried to convert a `CString` To BYTE*` and "BYTE* to CByteArray" in MFC, With Your Suggestions The CString Has Been Converted To BYTE*. But I'm not able to Convert The Entire Byte* To CByteArray It Returns Partial Data With Some Garbage Values.
I Described My Actual Problem Here...

The code:

```
CString csData =_T("someData");

BYTE *pByteArray = (PBYTE)(LPCTSTR)csData.GetBuffer();

CString str;
str=LPTSTR(pByteArray);
AfxMessageBox(str); //returns "someData" 

CByteArray arrByte2;

arrByte2.SetSize(csData.GetLength()+1);

memcpy(arrByte2.GetData(), pByteArray, csData.GetLength()+1);

CString text((LPTSTR)arrByte2.GetData(),arrByte2.GetSize());
CStringA result(text);
AfxMessageBox(text);//returns "some﵄﷽꯽ꮫꮫ"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LPCSTR, LPCTSTR and LPTSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/lpcstr-lpctstr-and-lptstr)

Comment: You asked the wrong question. Clearly, you have no issues converting the controlled sequence of characters to a `BYTE*`. Your real issue is, that you later fail to **interpret** that data appropriately. Besides, `GetBuffer()` is the wrong call (for one, it requires that you call `ReleaseBuffer()` later on). What you meant to call is [GetString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring) instead.

Comment: What are you _actually_  trying to achieve? This looks a bit like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
str = (LPCSTR(pByteArray));
```

You cast `pByteArray` to a `LPCSTR` which is actually a `const char *`. But as your program is compiled as UNICODE program, `CString` is a string of wide characters (`wChar_t`) and `pByteArray` points to an array of `wChar_t` (wide characters, or 16 bit characters). Look at the memory pointed by `pByteArray` with the debugger.

So the memory pointed by `pByteArray` looks like this:

```
's', 0, 'o', 0, 'm', 0,  etc.
|-----|
^ this is one wide char
```

and not like this as you expect:

```
's', 'o', 'm',   etc.
```

In order to correct, you need to cast to `LPTSTR` (as you're doing in the first part of the code snippet) and not to `LPCSTR`:

```
str = LPTSTR(pByteArray);
```

BTW the extra `()` around the expression are not necessary.

Comment: Great answer, might be worth noting that the first zero terminates the char*.

Comment: Thanks @Jabberwocky "str = LPTSTR(pByteArray);",Now The String Got Converted.

Comment: I Have Edited My Question To Portray The Exact Issue.Awaiting Your Response