# Packet.dll get mac address (JNR-FFI)

Tags: java, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, winpcap, jnr

How does one map the function below to java with jnr-ffi?

**BOOLEAN PacketRequest(LPADAPTER  AdapterObject,BOOLEAN Set,PPACKET_OID_DATA  OidData);**

Example (C): https://github.com/patmarion/winpcap/blob/master/WpcapSrc_4_1_3/Examples/PacketDriver/GetMacAddress/GetMacAddress.c

```
public interface NativeMappings {

    public static class PPACKET_OID_DATA extends Struct {

        public final UnsignedLong Oid = new UnsignedLong();
        public final UnsignedLong Length = new UnsignedLong();
        public final byte[] Data = new byte[6];

        public PPACKET_OID_DATA(Runtime runtime) {
           super(runtime);
        }

    }

    Pointer PacketOpenAdapter(String AdapterName);

    int PacketRequest(Pointer AdapterObject, int set, @Out PPACKET_OID_DATA OidData);

    void PacketCloseAdapter(Pointer lpAdapter);

    public static class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            NativeMappings mappings = LibraryLoader.create(NativeMappings.class).load("Packet");
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(mappings);
            Pointer adapterObject = mappings.PacketOpenAdapter("\\Device\\NPF_{53152A2F-39F7-458E-BD58-24D17099256A}");
            PPACKET_OID_DATA oid_data = new PPACKET_OID_DATA(runtime);
            oid_data.Oid.set(0x01010102L);
            oid_data.Length.set(6L);
            int status = mappings.PacketRequest(adapterObject, 0, oid_data);
            if (status == 0) {
                System.out.println("Fail.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Success.");
            }
            mappings.PacketCloseAdapter(adapterObject);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to make a propper mapping you should look at the definitions of types you are mapping. `PacketRequest` function returns `BOOLEAN` variable. According to [windows data type description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types), `BOOLEAN` is declared as `typedef BYTE BOOLEAN;`. That means, that you can use `byte` type as function type in java. But JNR also supports mapping `boolean` type to/from native `byte`. So both definitions are correct:

- `byte PacketRequest (...)`
- `boolean PacketRequest (...)`

Next, you need to map parameters. Same here, look at the definitions and you'll know what types to use. The result would be:

```
boolean PacketRequest(Pointer AdapterObject, boolean set, PPACKET_OID_DATA OidData);
```

The `set` parameter was incorrectly declared as `int`. Moreover the `@Out` annotation of the last field tells JNR to pass an empty structure without copying values to native memory. So no pre-set values will be passed.

The last parameter has `PPACKET_OID_DATA` type - a [structure](https://github.com/patmarion/winpcap/blob/master/Include/Packet32.h).

```
struct _PACKET_OID_DATA {
   ULONG Oid;                   ///< OID code. See the Microsoft DDK documentation or the file ntddndis.h
                                ///< for a complete list of valid codes.
   ULONG Length;                ///< Length of the data field
   UCHAR Data[1];               ///< variable-lenght field that contains the information passed to or received 
                                ///< from the adapter.
};
```

Structure mapping is a bit more complex than for native types. You can't use java types here. Instead you should use `jnr.ffi.Struct` inner classes to define struct fields. This rule includes array definitions. The correct definition for your structure will look like this:

```
class PPACKET_OID_DATA extends Struct {

    public final UnsignedLong Oid = new UnsignedLong();
    public final UnsignedLong Length = new UnsignedLong();
    public final Unsigned8[] Data = array(new Unsigned8[6]);

    public PPACKET_OID_DATA(Runtime runtime) {
        super(runtime);
    }

}
```

Notice this `UCHAR` array definition. Natively this type is defined as `unsigned char`, so for JNR structure it would map to `jnr.ffi.Strunc.Unsigned8` class or `jnr.ffi.Struct.BYTE` (which is pretty much the same).

To declare an array field you should initialize array in construction time. You need to use `jnr.ffi.Struct#array(...)` functions to do that properly. That aslo means that you should know the size of the array. The example is shown above.

**Why we should define it this way?**
During initialization, `Struct` is some kind of a pointer of variable length. Each inner-class field, initialized in it reserves its own space increases maximun size of this pointer. So each field is a "view" to some memory fragment with its own way of interacting with this memory (public methods). But to make an array of such views you need to fill the empty array with view instances. That is just what `array` function does.

Comment: May be the problem is with the string you pass to  `PacketOpenAdapter`. What encoding does the library require?

Comment: Can you check whether the `adapterObject` is NULL? If so, you should change string encoding.

Comment: LPADAPTER PacketOpenAdapter(LPTSTR AdapterName)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/lpcstr-lpctstr-and-lptstr
what is jnr native type for LPTSTR?

Comment: If it is null, try 
     `Pointer PacketOpenAdapter(@Encoding("ASCII") String AdapterName);`
or
`Pointer PacketOpenAdapter(@Encoding("UTF-16") String AdapterName);` declarations instead of the provided one.

Comment: I got error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6c0e5166, pid=3712, tid=0x000007d0 when using UTF-16

Comment: `LPTSTR` is a `String` of Unicode or ASCII encoding

Comment: is `adapterObject == null` when you use ASCII?

Comment: when ASCII adapterObject = jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.DirectMemoryIO[address=0x3aa138]

Comment: That means that adapter was successfully opened. Can you provide new main function code?

Comment: By the way, I just noticed that you added `@Out` annotation to the `PPACKET_OID_DATA` parameter. Remove it. It tells JNR not to send the data you set to the structure fields in the function on call.

Comment: Here's the code https://pastebin.com/raw/d8YZYJpQ
I'm using Jxnet to get adapter name.

Comment: Glad to help) You can upvote my answer if it was useful.

By the way, other JNR annotations you used are redudant too.